# e text editor bundles writing

Tags: e-texteditor

Where can one find some sort of a tutorial, or documentation for writing e text editor bundles which deal with automatization of certain processes (copying files from one directory to another, compiling using a new compiler (for which there isn't a premade bundle) and so on ...) ?

Answer (score 0):

iirc e uses the same bundle format as it's inspiration TextMate.

Check out their docs and see if they're helpful.  Also here is a [tutorial link](http://advws.blogspot.com/2009/03/creating-textmate-bundle.html), I'm not sure how much it carries over.

Comment: Yeah, e makes a big deal about that, and includes many TextMate bundles.